# HSQLException on session.list. Error: Unexpected token "Entity name"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I was working on the hibernate/JPA setup for one of the projects and I am running into strange error.

Whenever I try to do a session.list() call, I first get the below warning.

```
6565 [main] WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: -5581, SQLState: 42581
```

And after this , I get the following error.

unexpected token: ADSUBCONTE8_

Detailed stacktrace :-

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1858)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ADSUBCONTE8_
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ADSUBCONTE8_
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 55 more
```

The java classes for the two classes in the manyToOne relationShip are as below (With lines of interest highlighted)

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the ad_context_tags database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ad_context_tags")
@NamedQuery(name = "AdContextTagEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdContextTagEntity a")
public class AdContextTagEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "last_update_date")
    private Date lastUpdateDate;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to AdCategoryEntity
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private AdCategoryEntity adCategory;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to AdPageInfoEntity
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "page_info", nullable = false)
    private AdPageInfoEntity adPageInfo;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to AdSlotFamilyEntity
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "`slot_group`", nullable = false)
    private AdSlotFamilyEntity adSlotFamily;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to MarketplaceMappingEntity
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "siterealm")
    private LegacyMarketplaceMappingEntity marketplaceMapping;

// ========== the field that gives the error below. Class defined later in the post ======
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "subcontext")
        private AdSubcontextEntity subcontextEntity;

        public AdSubcontextEntity getSubcontextEntity()
        {
             return subcontextEntity;
        }

         public void setSubcontextEntity(AdSubcontextEntity subcontextEntity)
         {
             this.subcontextEntity = subcontextEntity;
          }


    public AdContextTagEntity()
    {
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy()
    {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy)
    {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate()
    {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate)
    {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdateDate()
    {
        return this.lastUpdateDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate)
    {
        this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
    }

    public AdCategoryEntity getAdCategory()
    {
        return this.adCategory;
    }

    public void setAdCategory(AdCategoryEntity adCategory)
    {
        this.adCategory = adCategory;
    }

    public AdPageInfoEntity getAdPageInfo()
    {
        return this.adPageInfo;
    }

    public void setAdPageInfo(AdPageInfoEntity adPageInfo)
    {
        this.adPageInfo = adPageInfo;
    }

    public AdSlotFamilyEntity getAdSlotFamily()
    {
        return this.adSlotFamily;
    }

    public void setAdSlotFamily(AdSlotFamilyEntity adSlotFamily)
    {
        this.adSlotFamily = adSlotFamily;
    }

    public LegacyMarketplaceMappingEntity getMarketplaceMapping()
    {
        return this.marketplaceMapping;
    }

    public void setMarketplaceMapping(LegacyMarketplaceMappingEntity marketplaceMapping)
    {
        this.marketplaceMapping = marketplaceMapping;
    }

    public DcAdLocation constructSerializable()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new DcAdLocation();
    }

}
```

And the class in question is as below :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ad_subcontext")
@NamedQuery(name="AdSubcontextEntity.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM AdSubcontextEntity a")
public class AdSubcontextEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=20)
    private String primary;

    @Column(length=11)
    private String secondary;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPrimary() {
        return this.primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(String primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public String getSecondary() {
        return this.secondary;
    }

    public void setSecondary(String secondary) {
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }


}
```

The SQL generated by hibernate is as follows :-

```
/**
 * select this_.id as id1_6_7_, this_.category as category5_6_7_,
 * this_.page_info as page6_6_7_, this_."slot_group" as slot7_6_7_,
 * this_.created_by as created2_6_7_, this_.creation_date as creation3_6_7_,
 * this_.foo as foo8_6_7_, this_.last_update_date as last4_6_7_, this_.siterealm
 * as sitereal9_6_7_, adcategory2_.id as id1_3_0_, adcategory2_.name as
 * name2_3_0_, adpageinfo3_.id as id1_8_1_, adpageinfo3_.page_family as
 * page5_8_1_, adpageinfo3_.browse_node as browse2_8_1_, adpageinfo3_.page_name
 * as page3_8_1_, adpageinfo3_.page_short_name as page4_8_1_, adpageamab4_.id as
 * id1_7_2_, adpageamab4_.amabotId as amabotId2_7_2_, adpageamab4_.family as
 * family3_7_2_, adslotfami5_.id as id1_12_3_, adslotfami5_."slot_family_name"
 * as slot2_12_3_, foo6_.id as id1_0_4_, foo6_.primary as primary2_0_4_,
 * foo6_.secondary as secondar3_0_4_, legacymark7_.id as id1_24_5_,
 * legacymark7_.client_id as client4_24_5_, legacymark7_.client_zone as
 * client2_24_5_, legacymark7_.marketplace_id as marketpl3_24_5_,
 * legacyclie8_.id as id1_19_6_, legacyclie8_.client_name as client2_19_6_ from
 * ad_context_tags this_ inner join ad_category adcategory2_ on
 * this_.category=adcategory2_.id inner join ad_page_info adpageinfo3_ on
 * this_.page_info=adpageinfo3_.id left outer join ad_page_amabot_mapping
 * adpageamab4_ on adpageinfo3_.page_family=adpageamab4_.id inner join
 * ad_slot_family adslotfami5_ on this_."slot_group"=adslotfami5_.id inner join
 * Foo foo6_ on this_.foo=foo6_.id left outer join marketplace_mappings
 * legacymark7_ on this_.siterealm=legacymark7_.id left outer join clients
 * legacyclie8_ on legacymark7_.client_id=legacyclie8_.id
 */
```

I did some investigation on my part as well and it looks like this ADSUBCONTE8 will get generated no matter what. I tried renaming it to Crap.java but then I kept getting the error as unexpected token Crap6. 
The tests and the build pass fine if I try to remove the AdSubContext from the parent AdContextTagEntity.

Please help me out as I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: The unexpected token appears nowhere in the posted SQL query.

Comment: It's in the stack trace. On the token ADSUBCONTE8_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the SQL was provided by you generated without the "subcontextEntity" field cause of it doesn't contain a join to the table ad_subcontext.

An exception is not in the Hibernate, but in HSQLDB driver. So, driver just can't parse a SQL by some reasons.

Possible reasons:

Using "primary", "secondary" as fields names — this names can be reserved for primary key and secondary key.

Using strange name "`slot_group`" in

```
@JoinColumn(name = "`slot_group`", nullable = false)
```

or other "field name" reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Primary and secondary field names were the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are right the warning and the exception are interrelated . Both warning and exception are pointing to unexpected token as specified [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hsqldb/sqltool/2.3.0/org/hsqldb/error/ErrorCode.java).

---

The exception is not in Hibernate, but probably in HSQLDB.The sub query seems to be the problem. Hsqldb doesn't seem to be able to parse sub queries.Some things we can try on it.(apologies if you already tried them)

1. Try changing the column names for `primary` and `secondary`.Basically check for reserved words as it is possible to have this error when you use some in naming.
2. Check through your SQL file if it is getting executed correctly in standalone mode and creating all tables with all expected constraints especailly related to `ad_subcontext` table.Saying this as dint find much in the generated query which you added to be question. Try the similar SQL on your DB i am quite sure it will have similar error.